# Prevent access to the page until the process is initiated by other visitors

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, email, cron

How to prevent access to the page until the process is initiated by other visitors? On one website I have hidden page what I trigger with cron job in particular time. On that page is script what generate daily email and send on 50.000 email adresses. That script inside it have pagination what I use to made group of sequences by 2000 users per each session. I find that sometimes cron job trigger page multiple times and I need to trigger only once. Also some Google and Bing spider find page in the same time when access cron job and trigger multiple times. I need prevent multiple triggers in the same time.

Here is main part of code for you to understand functionality of that page:

```
/* Start Class
===============================*/
global $$dbConn, $prefix, $config;
$dr = new prDailyRequests($dbConn, $prefix, false);
if($dr->send)
{
    $page = isset($_GET["page"]) ? $_GET["page"] : $dr->page;
    $lastpage = $dr->total;

    /* Redirect on pagination
    ===============================*/
    if(!isset($_GET["page"]) || !isset($_GET["total"]))
    {
        usleep(10);
        header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
        header("Location: ".$config->url."/index.php?component=request&option=trigger&page=".($page)."&total=".($lastpage));
        exit;
    }

    /* Send request on email
    ===============================*/
    else if($page <= $lastpage)
    {
        $page=$dr->send();
        usleep(10);
        header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
        header("Location: ".$config->url."/index.php?component=request&option=trigger&page=".($page)."&total=".($lastpage));
        exit;
    } else die();
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    exit;
}
```

In class `new prDailyRequests()` I have a functionality for collecting daily posts and user emails from site database, generate email template and send into InfusionSoft in sequence of 2000 users per page. I use database to store session and information when is send daily requests, how many users and in which page is the current script. Here is fields in database:

`id | total_users | current_page | totla_page | day | month | year | timestamp`

Do can help me PHP function `register_shutdown_function()` or I need to use some another approach?

For you to be clear, here is one example:

If I trigger that script and that script running, that script can work arround 30-40s. In that time when script work I need stop other visitor to trigger same script. I need prevent access to other visitors on that page while script work.

Thanks!

Comment: So, do you have a cronjob which sends the e-mails or is it the page? How are they connected to each other?

Comment: Cron job just trigger page where is this script. This script paginate itself until it sends the last sequence. In this script I collect all emails, daily posts, generate template for email and send via InfusionSoft iSDK-API `SendEmail` function.

Comment: So the same page is accessed by other users? You want to avoid the call when calling the page directly?

Comment: Maybe you can put some text in a file and verify on load if the text is present in the file, if there is no text, you can execute your script, if there is text, you don't execute script.

Comment: @AykutÇevik Well no but some Google and Bing spider find page in the same time when access cron job and trigger multiple times that page. Session table prevent this script to send email multiple times BUT if script is on half job and someone visit same page, the same sequence will start over. Session table also using `current_page` field prevent script to start from 0 page. If script stop for some reason on page 5 and max page is 7, after next visit, script will continue to work from page 5.

Comment: @ThomasRollet how to do that? Example: If I trigger that script and that script running, that script can work arround 30-40s. In that time when script work I need stop your visit to that page. I need prevent your access.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić When the first user load the page, you create a file named pageaccessok.txt with the content : "false", and run the script
When the second user access to the page, you check if the file pageaccessok.txt have the content "false", if there is that content, you don't run your script. When the first user has finished with the script, you change the content of the file

Comment: That's ok @ThomasRollet but that will also stop my script on next redirection. If you close look my code, you will see that I use GET pharams in URL to track pagination.